# Mountain Tribesmen in Hi Shin Tai

Tags: kingdom

In the manga Kingdom, several mountain tribesmen appeared as members of the Hi Shin Tai (飛信隊) during the battle against Gen Bou's (玄峰) army. These tribesmen had excellent hearing, which helped their unit escape the smokescreen trap of their enemy.

At this point the Hi Shin Tai was a "temporary" 1,000-member unit, so they must have joined Shin (信) sometime when they were just a 100-member unit. But was it shown or explained somewhere (what Chapter)? Were they from the same tribe as Yo Tan Wa (楊端和)?

Thanks for your time.